# Accessing elements of itertools product in a for loop

Tags: python

I have a list of list being the result of appending some other results from itertools product. What I want is to be able to access each element of the lists in the list of lists using for loop but I was unable to access all the elements. I was only able access elements of the last list. The result is a very huge list of lists like: [[1,2,],[4,3,6,19][2,0,34,9,9].........[n]]. I want to be able to access all the elements in each of the lists within the list of lists in a for loop but am getting only the elements of the last list. Itertools is only showing the location of the elements in memory.

```
myListofLists=[]                              
from itertools import product
animal = ['dog','cat']
number = [5,45,8,9]
color = ['yellow','blue','black']
myProduct = product(animal, number, color):
myListOfLists.append(myProduct)
for item in myListOfList:
   list(items)
```

Which makes the result something like this:[['dog',5,'yellow']['dog',45,'blue'],.......]
It is only showing  in the shell but I tried to write the result to a file, I can only see the elements of the last list.

My questions are(1)How can I access all the elements of each of the lists in the linked list and (2)how can I view the results in the python shell apart from showing me the location of the elements in memory. Thanks!

Comment: This post is incoherent.

Comment: Can we please have some example code? A sample input? Expected output? Actual output? Please edit your question.

Comment: @That1Guy. I made it a bit clearer now. Thanks

Comment: Obviously the code here doesn't match your code (it has a few syntax errors). Also, it doesn't do what you are trying to do (`list(item)` isn't going to write anything anywhere). Your problem is that you're trying to turn `myProduct` into a list the wrong way. Use this comprehension: `myProduct = [x for x in product(animal, number, color)]` and then work with that.

Answer (score 4):

`itertools.product` itself returns an object you can iterate over.  For example:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> animal = ['dog','cat']
>>> number = [5,45,8,9]
>>> color = ['yellow','blue','black']
>>> myProduct = product(animal, number, color)
>>> for p in myProduct:
...     print p
...     
('dog', 5, 'yellow')
('dog', 5, 'blue')
('dog', 5, 'black')
[...]
('cat', 9, 'blue')
('cat', 9, 'black')
```

After this, `myProduct` is exhausted (out of elements to yield) and so if you loop again you won't get anything:

```
>>> for p in myProduct:
...     print p
...     
>>>
```

If you want to materialize `myProduct` into a list, you can do that:

```
>>> myProduct = list(product(animal, number, color))
>>> len(myProduct)
24
>>> myProduct[7]
('dog', 8, 'blue')
```

By appending the `product` object itself to a list, you're not getting the list iterating it would produce, only the object.

```
>>> myProduct = product(animal, number, color)
>>> myProduct
<itertools.product object at 0x8e3ce3c>
```

If you want, you can store this object somewhere, and get elements from it the same way:

```
>>> some_list = [myProduct, myProduct]
>>> next(some_list[0])
('dog', 5, 'yellow')
>>> next(some_list[1])
('dog', 5, 'blue')
>>> next(some_list[1])
('dog', 5, 'black')
>>> next(some_list[0])
('dog', 45, 'yellow')
```

but here I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: How do I access each elements within the lists iteratively. For instance ['dog', 8, 'blue')], then move to the next list until all is exhausted. I think it will be more helpful if you have any idea on how to convert all the tuples to lists within the general list, thereby making it list of list and then accessing the elements of each list one after the other like: myListOfList = [['dog', 8, 'blue']['dog', 5, 'black'........[....]] and then access the elemnts with a for loop like: for items in myListofList

Comment: As done above, simply `listOfList = list(product(animal, number, color))` produces a list of tuples.

Comment: How do I access each elements within the lists iteratively. For instance ['dog', 8, 'blue')], then move to the next list until all is exhausted. I think it will be more helpful if you have any idea on how to convert all the tuples to lists within the general list, thereby making it list of list and then accessing the elements of each list one after the other like: myListOfList = [['dog', 8, 'blue']['dog', 5, 'black'........[....]] and then access the elemnts with a for loop like: for items in myListOfList:
                          for elem in items:

Comment: @user2553377 You don't need to repeat yourself. You want `[list(x) for x in product(animal, number, color)]` to get `[['dog', 8, 'blue'],['dog', 5, 'black'], ...]`.

Answer (score 2):

Reading your post many times, I think you are interested in this syntax:

```
for animal, number, color in ...:
```

It allows you to access the elements from the inner lists.

```
import itertools
animals = ['dog', 'cat']
numbers = [5, 45, 8, 9]
colors = ['yellow', 'blue', 'black']
for animal, number, color in itertools.product(animals, numbers, colors):
    print "Animal is {0}, number is {1}, and color is {2}".format(animal, number, color)
```

See this running on [ideone](http://ideone.com/znkSWV)

**EDIT:** Reading your comments in the other thread, I guess(?) you're interested in iterating over the inner tuples. You don't have to convert them to a list, you can simply iterate over them.

```
import itertools
animals = ['dog', 'cat']
numbers = [5, 45, 8, 9]
colors = ['yellow', 'blue', 'black']
for triplet in itertools.product(animals, numbers, colors):
    for element in triplet:
        print element
```

Demo on [ideone](http://ideone.com/kGEoRM)

**EDIT 2:** You can try that approach for your score thing.

```
import itertools
animals = ['dog', 'cat']
numbers = [5, 45, 8, 9]
colors = ['yellow', 'blue', 'black']
general_list = ['horse', 'blue', 'dog', 45]

def give_score(element):
    return 1 if element in general_list else 0

for triplet in itertools.product(animals, numbers, colors):
    print sum([give_score(element) for element in triplet])
```

Demo [here](http://ideone.com/J9BUCn)

Comment: Let us assume the result of the product is already obtaine this: All = [[dog,5,yellow],[dog,5,blue], [dog,5,black],[dog,45,yellow]......[]]. How do I go about accessing it. Thanks

Comment: @Gerald. Isaw it, it worked but I mean doing it separately for each list of the product:Animal is dog, number is 5, and color is yellow
Animal is dog, number is 5, and color is blue
Animal is dog, number is 5, and color is black as the first iteration

Comment: @user2553377 Still not completely sure where your problem is. Is the second option better fitting your needs?

Comment: @Gerald. Sorry for all the questions which may look stupid - am just a learner! In each of the tuples, let's assume there is a score associated with each item, will I be able to sum the scores for each tuples? Not all together. Can I have a demo? I must say your style expressiveness is highly commendable

Comment: @user2553377 Edit your original post to show us your code, exactly what you are trying to do, with sample input and output. (Obviously you aren't *just* trying to access sub-elements of a 2-D data structure.) Adding on this scoring thing has nothing to do with your original question.

Comment: @user2553377 I have to agree with the comment above. You're not doing yourself a favor here. It will be harder to help you if you can't be clear about your issues, and if you change the question in the middle.

Comment: @ Gerard and 2rsts. Am just learning and only try this after running your example. I dont have any code for it but I want to do is to compare each item in each tuple with a general list see if it is present and assign a score of 1 and if not 0,and then obtain the cumulative score for the elements in each of the tuple or list within the list of lists. i was doing it bit by bit since am just learning the syntax and structures in python. Don't be offended by my amateur attitude

Comment: @user2553377 I have added an example of how you can sum the score of elements within every inner tuple. Note: Please update the question, this is also part of Stackoverflow etiquette. This is my last update for tonight; going to sleep. Hope you found what you're looking for.

Comment: @Gerard. MAny thanks to you. You have been so helpful, I will update you tommoro